# Joomla different frontend and backend editor

Tags: text, joomla, editor

Is it possible to have a different frontend text editor and a backend text editor?
- My Authors want a Tiny easy editor
- I need a more complex editor in the backend

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about how to use Joomla.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try specifying TinyMCE as the default editor in Global Configuration.

New users should then be assigned TinyMCE as their default editor. You might need to edit current user account in User Manager and set them to use TinyMCE if they aren't already set to TinyMCE.

You can then install your preferred editor and set this preference in your own account in User Manager.

Comment: I totally forgot about the personal editor settings. Thanks! This is just what I need.

Answer (score 2):

The CK-editor component lets you assign different editorsettings to different usergroups etc.